antd RangePicker sometimes does not show EndDate
I'm using antd RangePicker version 3.22.0. I'm encountering a strange graphic behavior: When the first date is chosen, but the second is not, somtimes this appears: 
the end date 'disappears' and goes out of bounds of my disabled dates.
The code:
    return (
        <DatePicker.RangePicker
            dropdownClassName={props.customParams && "custom-date-picker"}
            open={props.isOpen}
            value={props.markedDate}
            format={dateFormat}
            disabledDate={props.customParams?.disabledDates ?? TimeUtils.isDateAfterToday}
            showTime
            onOk={props.onOk}
            style={{opacity: 0}}
            separator={""}
            getCalendarContainer={props.calendarContainer}
            onCalendarChange={props.onCalendarChange}
            renderExtraFooter={props.renderExtraFooter}
            dateRender={renderDate}
        />
    );
};

the callback onCalendarChange simply changes the props.markedDate.
Thank you!
